# Is execution of stream lazy when using findAny() after multiple transformations?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have following code situation:

```
 return modulePatternPairs.stream()
                .filter(it -> it.matches(absoluteFilePath))
                .map(ModulePatternPair::getModule)
                .findAny()
```

My question: before find any, is map of all previous values performed, or is it done lazily - is only one variable mapped and then result returned? Should I rather use:

```
 return modulePatternPairs.stream()
                .filter(it -> it.matches(absoluteFilePath))
                .findAny()
                .map(ModulePatternPair::getModule)
```

What if I do mapping first, and then filter and findAny?

Comment: How about reading [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps)?

Comment: just use the first snippet

Answer (score 3):

Note that your second snippet:

```
 return modulePatternPairs.stream()
            .filter(it -> it.matches(absoluteFilePath))
            .findAny()
            .map(ModulePatternPair::getModule)
```

really means:

```
 ModulePatternPair mp 
    = modulePatternPairs.stream()
            .filter(it -> it.matches(absoluteFilePath))
            .findAny();
 mp.map(ModulePatternPair::getModule)...
```

Which I think should answer your question -- the first statement runs a complete stream pipeline, which results in a single `ModulePatternPair`.  The first pipeline does the minimal element generation / filtering it needs to find one.  Then the second stream pipeline (which is kind of silly, because you've got a stream of one element), proceeds to do the mapping.  As one of the commenters mentioned, you should just run it as one pipeline (your first snippet), and all will be good.

Comment: Not exactly. `findAny()` returns an `Optional`, hence, the follow-up `.map` is applied to the `Optional` and does not start a new stream pipeline, but converts the `Optional` to another `Optional`. Not wrong, conceptionally,  and in the case of a `parallel` stream, it’ll guaranty that there is at most one evaluation of the mapping function, which `Stream.map` won’t guaranty, though developers should avoid functions for which it makes a difference. So it shouldn’t make a difference whether you write `.map(f).findAny()` or `.findAny().map(f)`.

Comment: @Holger seems to make a hobby of picking on the sloppy-but-incidental parts of my answers :)   But there was a point, which was: the way the first snippet is written, all as one chain, obfuscates where and when the computation happens.  If you write the pipeline as a single statement, as in my second version, it's generally going to be more obvious what's going on.